# Bootstrap Conflict

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

I would like some help, I'm developing a wordpress site where I use bootstrap and a plugin for woocommerce called "YITH" but when I put the jquery calls in header.php the plugin stops working, as if the bootstrap cdn calls conflict with the plugin. Currently I'm using these calls.

Comment: <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-J6qa4849blE2+poT4WnyKhv5vZF5SrPo0iEjwBvKU7imGFAV0wwj1yYfoRSJoZ+n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-wfSDF2E50Y2D1uUdj0O3uMBJnjuUD4Ih7YwaYd1iqfktj0Uod8GCExl3Og8ifwB6" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

Comment: Is the plugin already including jQuery?

Comment: yes the plugin uses jquery